# Spring MVC - AJAX/JSON - ResponseBody -> calling a service

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and I want to do a AJAX call to get a JSON message with a Set of Person objects.
I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getAllPersons();
});
function getAllPersons() {
    $.getJSON("person/allpersons", function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

The person/allpersons (REST URL) calls a RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/allersons", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ??? ???() {
    ???
}
```

I have a service implemented to get all Persons:

```
public interface IPersonService {
    public Person addPerson(Person p);
    ...
    public Set<Person> getAllPersons();
}
```

How can I call this service? So what do I have to place instead of the ???

I tried several things like this, but I get errors in my Eclipse IDE:

```
public @ResponseBody <Set>Person getSomething() {
    Set<Person> persons = IPersonService.getAllPersons();
    return persons;
}
```

Errors / Warnings:

```
The type parameter Set is hiding the type Set<E>
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAllPersons() from the type IPersonService
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Person>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method Person is wrong it should be Set

```
public @ResponseBody Set<Person> getSomething() {
    Set<Person> persons = new IPersonServiceImpl().getAllPersons();
    return persons;
}
```

and another thing is you can not call interface method directly, first you need to implement that method in implementation class.

`IPersonService.getAllPersons()`  This statement is wrong , here compiler considering it as static method `getAllPersons()` of `IPersonService` class.

```
public class IPersonServiceImpl implements IPersonService{
    public Set<Person> getAllPersons(){
     -- Your Business Logic
    }
    public Person addPerson(Person p){
     -- Your Business Logic
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I changed it and I get one more error with the service call: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAllPersons() from the type IPersonService. The service method is already implemented and I already used it with a Adobe Flex frontend and BlazeDS. But I do not get it running within my Java backend. (public class PersonServiceImpl implements IPersonService ... it exists...)

Comment: Thank you, now I get the error message: IPersonServiceImpl cannot be resolved to a type. The structure of the interface and the implementation is right (the same like you wrote it).

Comment: Oh sorry, calling the Implementation works. But isn't it wrong to call the implementation and not the service?